Positional errors for a billboard sprite
Im having problems with a billboard sprite system,
p1 the billboard sprites that are spoused to be static move when I turn.
p2 the missle does not display a billboard sprite when fired
p3 When I turn in a specific direction it crashes
here is the code for drawing billboard sprites:
 def draw(self, player_pos, player_rot, c):
# Calculate the position on the screen where the object should be drawn
    dx, dy = self.pos[0] - player_pos[0], self.pos[1] - player_pos[1]

# Calculate the distance between the player and the object
    dist = sqrt(dx**2 + dy/2)

# Calculate the angle between the player's direction and the object
    theta = player_rot - atan2(dy, dx)

# Convert the angle to the range [-pi, pi]
    while theta <= -pi:
        theta += 2*pi
    while theta > pi:
        theta -= 2*pi

# Calculate the size of the object based on its distance from the player
    size = c.win_size[1] / (abs(cos(theta)) * dist)

# Calculate the position on the screen based on the angle
    x = c.win_size[0]/2 + theta * c.win_size[0]/(2*pi)

# Rotate the object's texture to counteract the camera's rotation
    rotated_texture = pg.transform.rotate(self.texture, -player_rot)

# Resize the rotated texture based on the calculated size
    resized_texture = pg.transform.scale(rotated_texture, (int(size), int(size)))

# Draw the object using its resized texture
    win.blit(resized_texture, (x, c.win_size[1]/2 - size/2))

and here is the code for the game if you want to test it further:
Game.py (main):
import pygame as pg
import engine as e
import time
from math import atan2, pi, cos, sqrt

class GameObject:
    def __init__(self, pos, texture_path):
        self.pos = pos
        self.texture = pg.image.load(texture_path).convert_alpha()  # Load the object texture

    def draw(self, player_pos, player_rot, c):
    # Calculate the position on the screen where the object should be drawn
        dx, dy = self.pos[0] - player_pos[0], self.pos[1] - player_pos[1]
    
    # Calculate the distance between the player and the object
        dist = sqrt(dx**2 + dy/2)

    # Calculate the angle between the player's direction and the object
        theta = player_rot - atan2(dy, dx)

    # Convert the angle to the range [-pi, pi]
        while theta <= -pi:
            theta += 2*pi
        while theta > pi:
            theta -= 2*pi

    # Calculate the size of the object based on its distance from the player
        size = c.win_size[1] / (abs(cos(theta)) * dist)

    # Calculate the position on the screen based on the angle
        x = c.win_size[0]/2 + theta * c.win_size[0]/(2*pi)

    # Rotate the object's texture to counteract the camera's rotation
        rotated_texture = pg.transform.rotate(self.texture, -player_rot)

    # Resize the rotated texture based on the calculated size
        resized_texture = pg.transform.scale(rotated_texture, (int(size), int(size)))

    # Draw the object using its resized texture
        win.blit(resized_texture, (x, c.win_size[1]/2 - size/2))


class Projectile(GameObject):
    def __init__(self, start_pos, direction, speed=0.2):
        super().__init__(start_pos, 'ROKT.png')
        self.direction = direction
        self.speed = speed
        self.hit = False

    def update(self, env):
        if not self.hit:
            self.pos = e.forward(self.pos, self.direction, self.speed)
            if 0 <= self.pos[0] < len(env[0]) and 0 <= self.pos[1] < len(env):
                if e.check_collision(env, self.pos):
                    self.hit = True
                    self.texture = pg.image.load('boom.png')  # Change the texture to the explosion texture
                    time.sleep(0.8)
                    self.pos = None  # Set to None to indicate it should disappear

class Mini:
    def __init__(self, start_pos, direction, speed=2):
        self.pos = start_pos
        self.direction = direction
        self.speed = speed
        self.texture = e.Texture('ROKT.png')
        self.projectiles = []  # Store multiple projectiles

    def move(self):
        self.pos = e.forward(self.pos, self.direction, self.speed)

    def fire(self):
        direction_vector = e.calculate_direction(self.direction)  # Calculate the direction vector based on the rotation
        projectile = Projectile(self.pos, direction_vector)  # Pass the direction vector when creating a new Projectile
        self.projectiles.append(projectile)  # Add the new projectile to the list

    def update(self, env):  # Add the missing update method
        for projectile in self.projectiles:
            projectile.update(env)  # Call the update method of each projectile
            if projectile.pos is None:  # If the projectile has disappeared
                self.projectiles.remove(projectile)  # Remove the projectile from the list

c = e.Constants(render_distance=50)

pg.init()
win = pg.display.set_mode(c.win_size)
win.set_alpha(False)
clk = pg.time.Clock()

t = e.Texture('cPanel.png')

font = pg.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 20)

env = [
    [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
    [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
    [1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1],
    [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1],
    [1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
    [1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1],
    [1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
    [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1],
    [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
]

pos = [1.1, 1.1]
rot = 0

mini = Mini(pos, rot)

# Create a list to store game objects
game_objects = [GameObject([5, 1], 'sGore.png')]#, GameObject([2, 2], 'object2.png')]

run = True
while run:
    for ev in pg.event.get():
        if ev.type == pg.QUIT:
            run = False

    keys = pg.key.get_pressed()
    mov = pos
    if keys[pg.K_w]: mov = e.forward(pos, e.calculate_direction(rot), 0.04)
    if keys[pg.K_s]: mov = e.forward(pos, e.calculate_direction(rot), -0.04)
    if keys[pg.K_a]: rot -= 0.04
    if keys[pg.K_d]: rot += 0.04
    if keys[pg.K_SPACE]: mini.fire()  # Fire when space is pressed
    if e.check_collision(env, mov) == 0: pos = mov

    win.fill((0, 0, 0))
    for ray in range(c.rays):
        direction = e.calculate_direction(rot + c.rotations[ray])
        dis, position, block = e.cast_ray(c, pos, direction, env)
        if dis and position:
            for l in e.calculate_lines(c, dis, position, c.rotations[ray], ray, t):
                pg.draw.line(win, l[0], l[1], l[2], l[3])

    mini.update(env)  # Update the mini (and its projectiles if it exists) and pass the environment to the update method

    # Draw the game objects
    for obj in game_objects:
        obj.draw(pos, rot, c)  # Pass the player's position, rotation, and constants to the draw method

    # Draw the projectiles
    for projectile in mini.projectiles:
        if projectile.pos:
            screen_pos = [projectile.pos[0]*c.line_width, projectile.pos[1]*c.line_width]
            win.blit(projectile.texture, screen_pos)

    fps_counter = font.render(f'FPS: {round(clk.get_fps())}', True, (255, 0, 255))
    win.blit(fps_counter, (0, 0))

    clk.tick(60)

    pg.display.flip()

engine.py (game engine):
from math import sin, cos, radians, sqrt
import numpy
import PIL.Image

class Texture:
    __slots__ = ('data')
    def __init__(self, file_path):
        self.data = numpy.array(PIL.Image.open(file_path).getdata())
        
class Constants:
    __slots__ = ('win_size', 'rays', 'fov', 'text_res', 'ren_dist',
                 'center', 'line_width',
                 'rotations', 'x', 'base_offset', 'index_multi')
    def __init__(self, window_size=(1920, 1080), rays=120, fov=90, texture_resolution=256, render_distance=10):
        self.win_size = window_size
        self.rays = rays
        self.fov = fov
        self.text_res = texture_resolution
        self.ren_dist = render_distance
        
        self.center = (window_size[0] // 2, window_size[1] // 2)
        self.line_width = window_size[0] // rays
        
        self.rotations = []
        self.x         = []
        for ray in range(rays):
            self.rotations.append(radians(ray/(rays/fov) - fov/2))
            self.x.append(self.line_width*ray)
            
        self.base_offset = []
        self.index_multi = []
        for pixel in range(texture_resolution):
            self.base_offset.append(pixel - texture_resolution/2)
            self.index_multi.append(pixel * texture_resolution)

def vector_add(v1, v2):
    return [v1[0] + v2[0], v1[1] + v2[1]]

def vector_int_multiply(v1, number):
    return [v1[0] * number, v1[1] * number]

def calculate_direction(rotation):
    return (cos(rotation) + 0.00001, sin(rotation) + 0.00001)

def forward(start_pos, direction, speed):
    return [start_pos[0] + direction[0] * speed, start_pos[1] + direction[1] * speed]

def check_collision(environment, position):
    return environment[int(position[1])][int(position[0])]

def cast_ray(cts, start_pos, direction, environment):
    pos = [int(start_pos[0]), int(start_pos[1])]
    unit_step_size = (sqrt(1 + (direction[1] / direction[0]) ** 2), sqrt(1 + (direction[0] / direction[1]) ** 2))
    
    step = [0, 0]
    ray_length = [0, 0]
    if direction[0] < 0:
        step[0] = -1
        ray_length[0] = (start_pos[0] - pos[0]) * unit_step_size[0]
    else:
        step[0] = 1
        ray_length[0] = (pos[0] + 1 - start_pos[0]) * unit_step_size[0]
    if direction[1] < 0:
        step[1] = -1
        ray_length[1] = (start_pos[1] - pos[1]) * unit_step_size[1]
    else:
        step[1] = 1
        ray_length[1] = (pos[1] + 1 - start_pos[1]) * unit_step_size[1]
    
    distance = 0
    while distance < cts.ren_dist:
        if ray_length[0] < ray_length[1]:
            pos[0] += step[0]
            distance = ray_length[0]
            ray_length[0] += unit_step_size[0]
        else:
            pos[1] += step[1]
            distance = ray_length[1]
            ray_length[1] += unit_step_size[1]
        
        collision = check_collision(environment, pos)
        if collision > 0:
            collide_pos = vector_add(start_pos, vector_int_multiply(direction, distance))
            return (distance, collide_pos, collision)
    return (False, False, False)

def calculate_lines(cts, distance, ray_pos, rotation, ray, texture):
    height = 1 / (distance * cos(rotation)) * 3
    if ray_pos[0] - int(ray_pos[0]) / 1 < 0.01 or ray_pos[0] - int(ray_pos[0]) / 1 > 1 - 0.01:
        color_index = int(cts.text_res * (ray_pos[1] - int(ray_pos[1])))
    else:
        color_index = int(cts.text_res * (ray_pos[0] - int(ray_pos[0])))
    lines = []
    for pixel in range(cts.text_res):
        offset = cts.base_offset[pixel] * height
        lines.append((texture.data[color_index + cts.index_multi[pixel]][:-1], (cts.x[ray], cts.center[1] + offset), (cts.x[ray], cts.center[1] + offset - height), cts.line_width))
    return lines

here are all the images used (made by yours truly)
cPanel.png
sGore.png
please bug fix this its for a school project.

Maybe try a [mre], it often helps you understand your problem and it also makes it easier to understand for others and thus way more likely that others will help you. Also adding more information such as what happens when it crashes, or are there any errors, or how is it crashing, would be helpful. Also instead of trying to fix all these 3 errors at once take only one and try to fix that
